# pdftk: edit PDF file in-place

Tags: pdf

Using [PDFtk Server](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/), I want to rotate a PDF file 90˚ and save it in-place, to overwrite the input file.  I tried the following, but it fails, probably because it starts writing before the file is finished reading.

```
pdftk in.pdf cat 1-endright output - > in.pdf
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your operation bash overwrite in.pdf file before call pdftk. You can't do it that way. I would recommend something like

```
pdftk in.pdf cat 1-endright output in-new.pdf && mv in-new.pdf in.pdf
```

This command also protect you when converting fail - file would not be overwriten.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`moreutils`](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) `sponge` for this:

```
pdftk in.pdf cat 1-endright output - | sponge in.pdf
```

One bug I've found is that `pdftk` doesn't always return non-zero on error, meaning that `in.pdf` may be wiped (`sponge` doesn't wipe if zero exit status).

Comment: Just out of curiosity: do you know what mechanisms `sponge` uses to determine exit-code of a process piped into it? I'm a bit puzzled.